# 3 node computation setup application

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, grpc

I have three nodes (1 master, 2 slaves) each running a loop of Nth Iterations e.g 100. Once the master node runs its first iteration, the slave's node runs its first iteration, we have a variable called sum_of_all which basically is a counter. Since each loop has 100 iterations, we want to send counter values back and forth between slaves and master, meaning that the master node will only initiate the next iteration if it receives acknowledgment or variable value from the slave nodes and the slave can only run the second iteration if the master has completed its second iteration and has updated and send new sum_of_all value.

Programming Language: Python, Bash

I tried exploring features like these in grpc and apache Kafka but I am not sure which can work well, I have made a prototype using grpc but its way too buggy as no other application I have seen using grpc like this way.

Comment: Use Raft protocol to communicate between nodes, or use some shared database like Redis, Zookeeper, etcd, Hazelcast, etc to build a distributed counter

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - I think a centralized database would be easier.

If you want to do this with Kafka, send one event from the "leader" when an iteration finishes. Both "followers" can use unique `group.id` values to individually track that event. When they consume this, you run another iteration loop in each "follower", which then have their own events.

You will want to generate a unique UUID, or incremental ID (which will need to be tracked in some external, durable storage) within the "leader" so that "followers" can respond appropriately.

E.g. You need at least 3 topics

**leader-events**

```
uuid1 - done  # sent by the leader after iterations
```

**follower-state-events**

```
uuid1 - {"id":1, "state":"waiting"}     # send when follower starts-up
uuid1 - {"id":1, "state":"processing"}  # send when iteration starts 
uuid1 - {"id":1, "state":"done"}        # after first follower iterations
...
uuid1 - {"id":2, "state":"done"}        # after second follower iterations
```

You then need another consumer to create an aggregate topic based on N `state=="done"` events for a matching `uuid1` record key.

You can use Kafka Streams / ksqlDB to do this `reduce()`/`aggregate()` functions over the data and build a KTable of the final state per UUID.

**aggregate-events** (make a compacted topic)

```
uuid1 - 1   # after first follower is finished
uuid1 - 2   # after second follower is finished
```

Your leader will consume this aggregate topic and check the counter to know when to start its next iteration loop, then it will generate a new ID and start the process again.

If you want a global "all sum" counter, then you can run `max` function over the `aggregate-events` topic.